Hydrating objects in n:1-relationships TYPO3
Inside my Extbase extension, I have two classes ParentUser and Child.
The child table holds a reference to the parent_user
CREATE TABLE tx_xxx_domain_model_child (
    ...
    parent_user int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0'
)

The parent_user table doesn't know about the Child.
Is it possible to hydrate the ParentUser object in such a way, that it holds a ObjectStorage (or similar) of children.
I want to render a list of all ParentUsers with its children.
Note, I don't want the model to know about any repository. It would be nice to use the ProppertyMapper.

Some more Code:
TCA:
...
'parent_user' => [
    'exclude' => false,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:xxx/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_xxx_domain_model_child.parent_user',
    'description' => 'LLL:EXT:xxx/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_xxx_domain_model_child.parent_user.description',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'select',
        'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
        'foreign_table' => 'tx_xxx_domain_model_parentuser',
        'default' => 0,
        'minitems' => 0,
        'maxitems' => 1,
    ],
],


CREATE TABLE tx_xxx_domain_model_child (
    first_name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    last_name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    date_of_archive int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    state int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    parent_user int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0'
);


CREATE TABLE tx_xxx_domain_model_parentuser (
    first_name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    last_name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    email varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    city varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    zip varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    region varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    country varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    address varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    date_of_archive int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    state int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
);

Using:

TYPO3 v12.4.18 + Extbase
PHP 8.2.22


Yes that's possible.
Your Parent needs a field childs (Or similar).
/**
 * @var ObjectStorage<Child>|null
 */
#[Lazy()]
public ObjectStorage|null $childs;

In the ext_tables.sql you add that field to your Parent table:
childs    int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,

And in the TCA of your Parent you can add it like this:
    'childs' => [
        'label' => 'Childs',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'inline',
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_xxx_domain_model_child',
            'foreign_field' => 'parent_user',
        ],
    ],


Thanks for your Answer! So it's only possible if the parent table has a field of children? Because I would like to avoid this redundancy. @Mogens

The field in the parent table only saves the amount of children and not the uid's of the children. So you will not have any redundant data.

Do I have to attach the child Object to the Objectstore of the parent, when creating a new child (e.g. in new Action of the ChildController)? Because my Backend is showing the relation but in the database childs is still 0. @Mogens

The childs field should be updated, when you save the parent record in the backend. There is no need to attach the child object to the objectstorage. Just be aware, that the childs field not always shows the right amount of children. If you need that, then you must take care of that as you described in the ChildController e.g.

I only create records through the Action. Would you consider it good practice to attach the child object? Is there any downsides, like the property mapper not working correct?

I use it like this in several projects and do not know any downsides.

"Thanks for your Answer! So it's only possible if the parent table has a field of children? Because I would like to avoid this redundancy" the "count" field is needed. Something we are working to get rid of in the TYPO3 core. But not yet finished the quest - mabye v14 then.

For the n:1 part you do not need a object storage, as the sub model class can be directly used. For your example (TCA/tables) following should work:
Child Model
<?php 

class Child extends AbstractEntity {

  /** @var ParentUser|null **/
  protected ?ParentUser $parentUser = null;


  public function setParentUser(?ParentUser $parentUser = null): void
  {
    $this->parentUser = $parentUser;
  }

  public function getParentUser(): ?ParentUser
  {
    return $this->parentUser;
  }
}

See also https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/Extbase/Reference/Domain/Model.html#n-1-relationships

This is what I'm trying to avoid: "Once more the model of the author does not have a property containing the authors posts. If you would want to get all posts of an author you would have to make a query in the PostRepository taking one or both relationships (first author, second author) into account." - https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/Extbase/Reference/Domain/Model.html#n-1-relationships

Ok. Got it. Either use the solution from morgens or query all childs for a parent user in the repository/controller and combine it manually. But you should have more a bidirectonal than or omit the "parent_user" id in the "child" record. Having a repostory in a model violates the model<->service constraint. Morgens solution should be the way to go than (and ensure to use lazy) special when combined with this one on the child side to avoid cycle dependencies.
